# Fantasy book with elemental magic containing submarines

Tags: story-identification, books

I am currently looking for a fantasy book (trilogy actually I think) that I read years ago. Here is what I remember:

- The world has several nations (that seem to be elemental based if I remember correctly)
- There is a (fire based?) church in this world that tries to suppress everyone
- I think this world was mainly water and some islands, but what I am sure about is that the hero traveled with a submarine for at least some time in this book
- There is magic in the book (although no fireball throwing wizards if I remember correctly)
- the hero learns to fight and I think some magic too
- Sometime near the end the hero meets some kind of hidden nation/army that helps him (those also have submarines?!)

Although I now see so many parallels it has nothing to do with *Avatar*.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that seems to be it! Wasn't able to find that with my searches

Comment: [Always happy to help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)